# DataTable js error in J2EE

Tags: java, jquery, eclipse, datatables, tabletools

Iam developing a J2EE web application using struts in eclipse and i using a plugin for grid view (DATATABLES - Table tools ). But eclipse always throwing this build error below..
please can any one help me in this...

ERROR :

```
Internal validation error java.lang.ClassCastException: 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.MethodBinding cannot be cast to 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LocalVariableBinding at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleNameReference.localVariableBinding(SingleNa
 meReference.java:226) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.Expression.checkNPE(Expression.java:320) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.analyseCode(MessageSend.java:67) 
 at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleNameReference.analyseAssignment(SingleNa
 meReference.java:84) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.Assignment.analyseCode(Assignment.java:63) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.analyseCode(MethodDeclaration
 .java:91) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.analyseCode(AbstractM
 ethodDeclaration.java:110) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.FunctionExpression.analyseCode(FunctionExpressio
 n.java:74) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.FieldReference.analyseAssignment(FieldReference.j
 ava:91) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.Assignment.analyseCode(Assignment.java:63) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.analyseCode(MethodDeclaration
 .java:91) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.analyseCode(AbstractM
 ethodDeclaration.java:110) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.FunctionExpression.analyseCode(FunctionExpressio
 n.java:74) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.analyseCode(LocalDeclaration.java
 :73) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.analyseCode(MethodDeclaration
 .java:91) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.analyseCode(AbstractM
 ethodDeclaration.java:110) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.FunctionExpression.analyseCode(FunctionExpressio
 n.java:74) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.analyseCode(MessageSend.java:86) 
 at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.analyseCode(MethodDeclaration
 .java:91) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.analyseCode(AbstractM
 ethodDeclaration.java:110) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.FunctionExpression.analyseCode(FunctionExpressio
 n.java:74) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.Expression.analyseCode(Expression.java:184) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.analyseCode(MessageSend.java:65) 
 at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.analyseCode(Compilation
 UnitDeclaration.java:155) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:606) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.
 java:288) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:
 86) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.
 java:227) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:
 58) at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:291) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:199) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728) at 
 org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292) at 
 org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: Please refer this bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391880

Answer (score 0):

Datatables 1.9.4 js causing the issue. This issue should be resolved now in WTP 3.5.1. Checked against 7/18 build. or the workaround is to remove the javascript validator from the project builders list.